# my Windows 7 doesn't boot at all?

Tags: windows-7, windows, boot

I have a problem with my Windows 7 Ultimate. It can't boot from the hard drive but it boots from a Windows Ultimate DVD. I tested:

- `bootrec.exe  /fixmbr`
- `bootrec.exe  /fixboot`
- `bootrec.exe  /RebuildBcd`

The first and second command complete successfully, but the rebuild command doesn't. When it tries to boot there is only a black screen without any pm.

I tried to run the OS repair from the Windows disc, despite seeing the message that it completed, the same error persisted.

What should I do now?

Comment: Boot from Windows DVD and repair the system?

Comment: I did it but it doesnt work.

Comment: Sigh... Doesn't work means? The disc is broken? No options to do this? The repair wasn't successful? The disc forces the PC to melt?

Comment: it means it wasent successful and with a recovery dvd it said successful repair but agian it cant boot.

Comment: my windows is original and I prefer dont reformat it.

Comment: oh,it is bad news.are u sure this is the only way?

Comment: What version of Windows 7 did your laptop ship with? And what version is the disc? As for the only way, no. There may be other answers which are less drastic, give it a day or two and see if anyone else answers. If no other answers, then you may be out of luck! Sorry.

Comment: my windows 7 is ultimate version sp1.and my dvd is also the same.by the way thanks for ur replies.

Comment: What does `bootrec /scanos` display?

Comment: the scan is ok but again I have the problem.

Comment: I also tried with code not only by GUI.

Comment: I install another win7 on D drive,also it cant boot!!!!!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you have the original serial and a disc (if not I suggest you legally [download the Windows 7 .iso](http://www.mydigitallife.info/official-windows-7-sp1-iso-from-digital-river/))  your option here is to reformat. Take note to use the same version of Windows as yours is shipped with (ie, Ultimate, Professional etc).

Rememeber, you can take out the hard drive, slave it to another machine and get a copy. This may result in saving some files (depending on the issues).